# Continuity with respect to hitting time level

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

Let $\tau(x)$ be the first hitting time of a Lévy process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ to level $x$. Let $f$ be a continuous function and $g(x)=\mathbb{E}[f(\tau(x))]$. Is it obviously true that $g$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be right for Poisson process.